# Is the set of linear functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equicontinuous?

Tags: analysis

By the set of linear functions I mean the functions of the form $$f(x)=\alpha x,$$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. We clearly have for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\alpha||x-y|.$$ So for any $\epsilon>0$, $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{|\alpha|}$ gives uniform continuity. However this $\delta$ is different depending on $f$, so it cannot give equicontinuity. I am having trouble figuring out how to show that there would be no $\delta$ that would work.

Comment: the very concept of equicontinuity is that the functions have the "same" growth rate in a small neighborhood, where it is obvious that these don't :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an argument.

Suppose that your set of functions *is* equicontinuous on $[0,1]$.
Then, given $\epsilon >0,$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that
$|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.
But if we pick $x,y$ such that $|x-y| = \delta/2$, then

$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = |a||x-y| = |a|\delta/2.
$$

If choose $a$ large enough, say $a=4\epsilon/ \delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)| = 2 \epsilon > \epsilon$, a contradiction.

(Note that our assumption that there exists $x,y$ such that $|x-y| = \delta/2$ is harmless.)